# Rails helper stopping controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller using a helper method for getting 'my current_stuff'. I would like to stop my controller method executing from my helper.

```
def controller_method
  helper_method.do_something
  #some code
end

def helper_method
  if something
    return current_stuff
  else
    #send 401 code and stop controller_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could raise an exception and catch it in the controller, but it's definitely not the best approach especially because you should not reuse view helpers inside your controller.

Split the controller from the helper. If the method performs some computation, you can always make the result available to the view once the computation finishes.

Comment: Actually my helper_method is used to get my current_stuff many times in my code and I would like to send an error to my client app (I develop an API) if cannot find this current_stuff. That is why I cannot split my helper from my controller. Imagine current_stuff to by current_article of a newspaper, my controllers would be full of raise an exception and catch

Comment: I still can't understand why you can't split it. You can always memoize the result to avoid multiple execution of the helper.

Comment: current_article is used in many controller methods. I use this method to get my article from params sent by my client app. If this article does not fit with some other params I send a 404. But if it does, it returns an article. I would like to avoid to check if those params are not correct in each method of my controllers